# Calculating generalized eigenvectors, when there is no solution

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A=\begin{pmatrix}7&0&0&0\\36&1&36&-30\\0&0&7&1\\0&0&0&7\end{pmatrix}$

For the eigenvalue $\lambda=7$, the basis for the eigenvectors is $\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{6}\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$.

I've taken the vector $6\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{6}\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\6\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=v_1$.

Next, the second vector can be found by solving $(A-7I)v_2=v_1$.

Solving, it I got $v_2=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

The problem is with finding $v_3$: $(A-7I)v_3=v_2$ doesn't have a solution.

What to do in such case?

Comment: You already found three vectors, two eigenvectors and $v_2$. That matches the algebraic multiplicity of $7$. Therefore, there are no more linearly independent generalized eigenvectors

Comment: Put another way, the characteristic polynomial is $(x-7)^3 (x-1)$  while the minimal polynomial is $(x-7)^2 (x-1).$ The exponent 2 says that the largest Jordan block for eigenvalue 7  is of size 2. The other 7 block is of size one. a